# Can't stay on same page/route after closing modal window in Angular JS on iPad

Tags: javascript, ipad, angularjs, cordova

Here is the issue. I'm using Angular JS + Phonegap for an iPad app and I'm trying to stay in the same route when on a page after closing a modal window with a video embedded in it.

The problem I had originally was that the video would not stop playing after closing the modal window, so I added an `onTouchStart` event for the `closeWindow()` like so:

```
<div class="modal-youtube" ng-class="{visible: modalActive}">
    <a class="close" href="#/mypage/#" eat-click ng-click="closeVideo()" onTouchStart="closeVideo()"></a>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" ng-show="youtubeLink" ng-src="{{youtubeLink}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

This works for stopping the video when closing, however, when closing the video now it wants to go to the home page. I changed the `href="#"` to what it is now `href="#/mypage/#` in order to at least stay on the page I want to be, but not in the same route.

For example, I have a few different videos on separate routes or urls like: 
  #/mypage/product1, #/mypage/product3, #/mypage/product6

Here's are the functions for playing and closing the video:

```
$scope.youtubeLink = null;
$scope.modalActive = false;
$scope.playVideo = function() {
    $scope.youtubeLink = angular.copy($scope.product.youtube);
    $scope.modalActive = true;
};

$scope.closeVideo = function() {
    $scope.youtubeLink = null;
    $scope.modalActive = false;
};
```

Any fix or help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the href actually used? If not, just remove it or change the <a> to a <div> or <button>.

Comment: @moderndegree I can't remove it, because the video won't stop playing otherwise. Only on iPad though, which is where I need it to work. Changing to a <div> or <button> didn't work either. It's a quirk in Angular.

Comment: See if `href=""` works.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Unfortunately, it didn't. I did find a work around using the ChildBrowser instead to display the video. However, there's another bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17796191/refresh-angular-route-by-clicking-done-button-in-childbrowser