# Previous Page in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

i am working in AngularJs and i have a problem.

When the user push the login button, the page go back to the previous page, but i only want go back if one of the routeprovider page and go to "/" route if teh previous page is another page. Actualy i use:

```
       if (history.length > 1)
        {
            history.back();
        }
        else
        {
            $location.url("/");
        }
```

How can i see the previous page url and compare it?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript allows navigation based on `window.history`, but it does not allow reading the actual history. So you cannot check the previous URL.

You may want to try `document.referrer` to check the previous URL (before entering the AngularJS app, I presume, as after entering you do not reload the page).

You may also build your history manually in AngularJS to see whether you have previously been navigating through your application: [angularjs getting previous route path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175429/angularjs-getting-previous-route-path)

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(next, current) { 
  ... you could trigger something here ...
});
```

Please refere to $routeChangeStart of angular which might help you for your query.