# angular, not executing script in order

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use angular 1.5 on a project since 1 year. It work good until 2 days.
( I use the same file hierarchy since the begining. )

*I cannot make a plunker because i have too many files (>100) but i can provide a zip with all the sources files.*

**What the problem is :**

I put configuration variables into $rootScope and inject it into manies services/controller to get the configuration and use them ( for example path to my webserver or elasticsearch )

The problem i have now is the service are runned before variable has been added to $rootScope so i get undefined variables !

**The console log:**

```
> "loading router.js" (from router.js (ligne 2))
> "end router"  (from router.js (ligne 353))
> ERROR : "$rootScope.elastic_host undefined" (from elasticsearch.js (ligne 4) )
> "loading rootscope" (from rootscope.js (ligne 3))
> "end rootscope" (rootscope.js (ligne 96))
```

**So elasticsearch.js is runned before rootscope.js even if the file a loaded before in the script.**

I try to change 'script' order or adding "defer" in 'script' but no change.

DETAILS :

**My index.html with the scripts loading :**

```
.....
<script type='text/javascript' src="resources/vendors/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="resources/vendors/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="resources/vendors/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='resources/vendors/angular/ng-onload.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/shared/tools.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/shared/countries.tools.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/router.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/rootscope.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/directives/directives.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/directives/directivesCarrousel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/filters/filters.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/services/carrousel.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/services/tumblr.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/services/elasticsearch.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/services/geographie.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/services/services.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/services/cas.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src="js/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
```

**router.js**

```
'use strict';
 console.log("loading router.js");
/* App Module */
// add the modules her, don't forget to load the js file in /index.html with <script source="">
var interfaceApp = angular.module('interfaceApp', [
   'ngRoute','oc.lazyLoad', 'ngOnload',
   'ui.bootstrap',
   /*'ngMaterial',*/
   'ngMessages',
   'filters','directives',
   'elasticsearch',
   'pascalprecht.translate',
   'ngCookies',
   'ngAnimate',
   'ngDialog',
   'angular-confirm',
   'ui-notification',
   'ngPapaParse','uuid4','angular-momentjs'
]
);

/**
 * routage, permet d'associer une url à un controller et vue, possible de mettre des parametres dans les urls
*/
angular.module('interfaceApp').config(['$routeProvider',
   function ($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.
          when('/', {
             templateUrl: 'partials/home/home.html',
             controller: 'homeController',
             resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                   return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/homeController.js']});
                }]
             }
          }).
          when('/test', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/test/index.html',
              controller: 'testController',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/testController.js']});
                  }]
              }
          }).
          when('/users', {
             templateUrl: 'partials/users/index.html',
             controller: 'usersController',
             resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                   return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/usersController.js']});
                }]
             }
          }).
          when('/gestionusers', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/gestionusers/index.html',
              controller: 'gestionusersController',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/gestionusersController.js']});
                  }]
              }
          }).
          when('/user/:login?', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/user/index.html',
            controller: 'userController',
            resolve: {
               lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                  return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/userController.js']});
               }]
            }
          }).
          when('/add/:domaine', {
             templateUrl: 'partials/add/add.html',
             controller: 'addController',
             resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                   return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      serie: true,
                      files: ['resources/json/countries.geo.min.js','resources/json/stratigraphie.js','resources/vendors/leaflet/all.leaflet.min.js', 'resources/vendors/leaflet/all.leaflet.min.css', 'js/directives/directiveMiniMap.js' ,'js/controllers/addController.js']
                   });
                }]
             }
          }).
          when('/edit/:domaine/:id', {
             templateUrl: 'partials/edit/edit.html',
             controller: 'editController',
             resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                   return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                      serie: true,
                      files: ['resources/json/countries.geo.min.js','resources/json/stratigraphie.js','resources/vendors/leaflet/all.leaflet.min.js', 'resources/vendors/leaflet/all.leaflet.min.css', 'js/directives/directiveMiniMap.js' ,  'js/controllers/editController.js']
                   });
                }]
             }
          }).
          when('/specimenpreview/:domaine/:id', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/specimenpreview/view.html',
              controller: 'specimenpreviewController',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                          serie: true,
                          files: ['js/controllers/specimenpreviewController.js']
                      });
                  }]
              }
          }).
          when('/copy/:domaine/:id', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/copy/copy.html',
              controller: 'copyController',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                          serie: true,
                          files: ['resources/json/countries.geo.min.js','resources/json/stratigraphie.js','resources/vendors/leaflet/all.leaflet.min.js', 'resources/vendors/leaflet/all.leaflet.min.css', 'js/directives/directiveMiniMap.js' ,  'js/controllers/copyController.js']
                      });
                  }]
              }
          }).
          when('/demos', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/demos/index.html',
              controller: 'demosCtrl',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/demosController.js']});
                  }]
              }
          }).
          when('/apropos', {
             templateUrl: 'partials/apropos.html'
          }).
          when('/plansite', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/plansite.html'
          }).
          when('/feedback', {
             templateUrl: 'partials/feedback.html',
             controller: 'feedbackCtrl',
             resolve: {
                lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                   return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/feedbackController.js']});
                }]
             }
          }).
          when('/editionlot/:domaine/:collectioncode', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/editionlot/index.html',
              controller: 'editionlotController',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/editionlotController.js']});
                  }]
              }
          }).
          when('/importlot/:domaine/:collectioncode', {
              templateUrl: 'partials/importlot/index.html',
              controller: 'importlotController',
              resolve: {
                  lazy: ['$ocLazyLoad', function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                      return $ocLazyLoad.load({files: ['js/controllers/importlotController.js']});
                  }]
              }
          }).
          otherwise({
             redirectTo: '/'
          });
   }]);


/**
* provider pour la traduction des textes
**/
angular.module('interfaceApp').config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
// Translation
   $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix: 'resources/i18n/traduction_',
      suffix: '.json'
   });
   $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('fr');
   $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('fr');
   $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
}]);
/**
 * safe scope $Apply
 * usage :
 * $rootScope.safeApply( $scope );
 * or
 * $rootScope.safeApply(function() { $scope.XX = YY ; ... });
 */
angular.module('interfaceApp').config([
   '$provide', function($provide) {
      return $provide.decorator('$rootScope', [
         '$delegate', function($delegate) {
            $delegate.safeApply = function(fn) {
               var phase = $delegate.$$phase;
               if (phase === "$apply" || phase === "$digest") {
                  if (fn && typeof fn === 'function') {
                     fn();
                  }
               } else {
                  $delegate.$apply(fn);
               }
            };
            return $delegate;
         }
      ]);
   }
]);


/**
 * Controller pour la traduction
 */
angular.module('interfaceApp').controller('TranslateCtrl', ['$rootScope','$scope', '$translate','$cookieStore', function ($rootScope, $scope, $translate,$cookieStore) {
   if( tools_defined($cookieStore.get('navigatorLanguage'))){
      //recharge l'ancien choix de langue de l'utilisateur si il existe
      $scope.navigatorLanguage =  $cookieStore.get('navigatorLanguage') ;
   }else {
      // sinon utilise langue du navigateur
      $scope.navigatorLanguage = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
   }
   // cl('$scope.navigatorLanguage: '+$scope.navigatorLanguage);
   $scope.translatedLanguage = [ 'fr','en'] ;
   if( tools_defined($scope.navigatorLanguage) && tools_inArray( $scope.navigatorLanguage,$scope.translatedLanguage )){

   }else{ // si la langue du navigateur n'est pas présente dans les traductions on prend l'anglais par défaut
      $scope.navigatorLanguage = 'en';
   }
   $translate.use( $scope.navigatorLanguage );
   $rootScope.navigatorLanguage = $scope.navigatorLanguage;

   $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
      cl("change langue");
      $cookieStore.put('navigatorLanguage', key );
      $scope.navigatorLanguage = key ;
      $rootScope.navigatorLanguage = key ;
      $translate.use(key);
   };
}]);

/**
 * Controller pour la gestion de l'authentification unqiue 
 *
 */
angular.module('interfaceApp').controller('AuthentificationCtrl',  AuthentificationCtrl);
AuthentificationCtrl.$inject = [ 'cas', '$location', '$rootScope', '$scope' ];
function AuthentificationCtrl(cas, $location, $rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.tgc = null; $scope.st = null;  var vm = this; var frame = document.getElementById("Menu").contentWindow;  vm.frame = frame;   $scope.init = function auth() {  vm.dataLoading = true;  $scope.tgc = getTGCCookiesValue(); if ($scope.tgc) { // on récupère le ST cas.GetServiceTicket($scope.tgc).then( function(response) { if (response.status == 200) { $scope.st = response.data; // on termine le processus de connexion validate(); } else { //FlashService.Error(response.message); vm.dataLoading = false; } });  } else {   };    function validate() {  cas.ValidateService($scope.st).then(function(response) { if (response.status == 200) { var data = response.data; var splitdata = data.split('\n'); var login = splitdata[1];  frame.postMessage({ type : "user", username : login, userProfile : "/user/"+login }, "https://www.recolenat.org/menu/");  } else { //FlashService.Error(response.message); vm.dataLoading = false; } }); }  function getTGCCookiesValue() { var fname = getCookie('CASTGC'); return fname; }  function getCookie(cname) { var name = cname + "="; var ca = document.cookie.split(';'); for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) { var c = ca[i]; while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1); if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length); } return null; } 
}


angular.module('interfaceApp').run(function ($rootScope, $location,cas,$timeout) {
   /**
    * executé avant chaque changement de route
    * modifie la variable globale filAriane utilisée dans chaque controller pour créer le fils d'ariane (pour revenir en arrière)
    */
   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175429/angularjs-getting-previous-route-path
   $rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
      $rootScope.filAriane.lasturl = $rootScope.filAriane.currenturl ;
      $rootScope.filAriane.currenturl = encodeURIComponent($location.$$path);
      $rootScope.isIndexPage = $location.$$path == "/";
   });
    $timeout( function(){
        cas.getUser("natg94").then( function(res){
            $rootScope.currentUser =  res ;
        });
    }, 1000);
});

console.log("end router.js");
```

**The rootscope.js**

```
angular.module('interfaceApp').run(function ($rootScope) {
   console.log("loading rootscope");

   // elasticsearch serveur host
   $rootScope.elastic_host = 'https://search.recolenat.org/' ;

   // adresse de l'interface de saisie
   $rootScope.saisie_host = 'https://saisie.recolenat.org/#/' ;

   // api, host for java web service

   $rootScope.api = 'http://localhost:8080/erecolenat/v1/' ;

   // elasticsearch index global
   $rootScope.elastic_global = "global";

   ....

   /* safe scope apply to avoid "digest already in"
    * $rootScope.$safeApply(fctA());
    * */
   $rootScope.$safeApply = function () {
      var $scope, fn, arg, force = false, args = arguments;
      if (args.length === 1) {
         arg = args[0];
         if (typeof arg === 'function') {fn = arg;} else { $scope = arg; }
      } else if (args.length > 0) {
         $scope = args[0]; fn = args[1];if (args.length === 3) {force = !!args[2]; }
      }
      $scope = $scope || this || $rootScope;
      if ($scope === window) { $scope = $rootScope; }
      fn = fn || function () {};
      if (force || !($scope.$$phase || $scope.$root.$$phase)) {$scope.$apply ? $scope.$apply(fn) : $scope.apply(fn);} else { fn(); }
   };
   console.log("end rootscope");
});
```

**elasticsearch.js**

```
// Create the es service from the esFactory
angular.module('interfaceApp').service('elasticQuery', function ($rootScope,esFactory) {
   if(!tools_defined($rootScope.elastic_host)){
      console.error("$rootScope.elastic_host undefined");
   }
   return esFactory({ host: $rootScope.elastic_host});
});
```

Comment: Remove  console.error("$rootScope.elastic_host undefined"); from elasticsearch.js

Comment: the problem still the same. elasticsearch.js is called before adding variable in $rootscope

Comment: You Got same Error Again??

Comment: yes. removing the console.error() will not display the error but the `$rootScope.elastic_host` still undefined because elasticsearch.js is called before adding variable in $rootscope

Comment: Otherwise you can use $broadcast Event.

Comment: thanks. i will read about it. I found that if i put the last part of the 'router.js' ( `angular.module('interfaceApp').run(function ($rootScope, $location,cas,$timeout) { .....})` ) in the end of 'rootscope.js' it work. but why ??